# Passing two arguments to nested where results in "and `` is null" appended to query

Tags: mysql, laravel, where-clause

```
      if ($input['search']) {
            $args = array($query, $input);
            $query->where(call_user_func_array(function($query, $input) {
                $query->where('tbl_products.name', 'LIKE', '%' . $input['search'] . '%')
                    ->orwhere('sku', 'LIKE', '%' . $input['search'] . '%');
            }, $args));
        }
    }
    return $query;
```

Above is a section of my query where I intend to create a nested where clause that resembles:

```
WHERE
    m.name = 'name' AND
    (p.name LIKE "% example %" or p.sku LIKE "% example %")
```

I've made use of the 'call_user_func_array' to pass in multiple arguments to the closure (only way I could pass the user input to the where clause).

Unfortunately I receive a query exception that looks a little like this:

> Unknown column '' in 'where clause'
>    ...`name` LIKE %example% or `sku` LIKE %example% and `` is null

and `` is null has been appended to the end. I think this is something to do with the original where clause needing two arguments but I'm struggling to get around it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
if ($input['search']) {
    $query->where(function ($query) use ($input) {
        $query->where('tbl_products.name', 'LIKE', '%' . $input['search'] . '%')
            ->orWhere('sku', 'LIKE', '%' . $input['search'] . '%');
    });
}
```

You can pass variables to a closure via `use`.

Reference: [Anonymous Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call `call_user_func_array` and you did it wrong. For nested `where` clause, in your case you nay use something like this:

```
// Assumed that you have $query variable, so

$query
->where('m.name', 'name') // = is optionl
->where(function($query) use ($input) // use copies the variable inside the function scope
{
    $query
    ->where('p.name', 'LIKE', '%' . $input['search'] . '%')
    ->orWhere('p.sku', 'LIKE', '%' . $input['search'] . '%');
});
```

This is an example to structure your query but probably you need to adjust because you didn't provide enough information.

Comment: Yeah cheers, didn't know 'use' was a thing. Very much a novice. Appreciate the advice though.